# Find the area enclosed by $\sqrt[4]{\frac{x}{a}}+\sqrt[4]{\frac{y}{b}}=1$

Tags: calculus, integration

If $a >0$ and $b>0$ I need to find the area of the region enclosed by the curves $$\sqrt[4]{\frac{x}{a}}+\sqrt[4]{\frac{y}{b}}=1,\;x=0,\;y=0$$ I was thinking some kind of polar coordinate change but could not work it out.

Comment: This is a [superellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) of order $n=\dfrac14$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply integrate directly.  Note that

$$\frac{y}{b} = \left [1-\left (\frac{x}{a}\right)^{1/4}\right]^4$$

and this may be expanded by the binomial theorem.

$$\left [1-\left (\frac{x}{a}\right)^{1/4}\right]^4 = 1-4 \left (\frac{x}{a}\right)^{1/4}+ 6 \left (\frac{x}{a}\right)^{1/2} - 4 \left (\frac{x}{a}\right)^{3/4} + \frac{x}{a} $$

The resulting integrals are easy, and the result is

$$\int_0^a dx \, y = \frac{a b}{70}$$

Comment: The simple the better.Love your way of writing $dx$ before the integrand. :-) +1

Comment: @B.S.: many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this substitution with:

$$x=ar^4\cos^8(t),~~y=br^4\sin^8(t),~~0\le t\le \pi/2,0\le r\le 1 $$ where $J(x,y)=32abr^7(\cos^7(t)\sin^7(t))$. But as we see the Ron's way is very simple than integrating this messy trigonometric function.